# There are a lot of comment lines in the terminal window (RSpec testing, Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

After RSpec tests run I every time have results with a lot of comment lines. Do you have any thought why they appear? May be somebody had the same problem?

An example of problem comments:

```
1) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:432:in `form_for'
     # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb__4109427626355592215_70195532470880'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
     # /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /Users/smi/.......................etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not comment lines. That is the stacktrace of the `ActionView::Template::Error` exception that is generated running the test.

The test is clearly failing with the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

The stack trace is helpful for debugging purposes. For instance, in this case you need to research the issue at

```
# ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:7
```

There is probably a `form_for` around an object that was not expected to be `nil`, but it was.

Fix the bug, and the error and the backtrace will not longer show up.